# Obtain values from embedded tables Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am new to Lua and I am trying to learn how to make a function with embedded tables. I am stuck trying to figure out a way to make the function meet specific values in the table.

Here is an example of a table:

```
    TestTable = {destGUID1 = {catagory1 = {A=1,B=5,C=3},catagory2 = {A=5,B=3,C=2}},destGUID2 = {catagory1 = {A=1,B=5,C=3},catagory2 = {A=5,B=3,C=2}}}
```

Now I want to make a function for this table that pulls values only from the specific destGUID. Like:

```
function CatInfo(GUID,Cat)
    for i=1, #TestTable do
        if TestTable[i] == GUID then
            for j=1, TestTable[i][GUID] do
                if TestTable[i][GUID][j] == Cat then
                    return TestTable[i][GUID][Cat].A -- returns value "A"
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

So that when I use this function, I can do something like this:

```
    CatInfo(destGUID2,catagory1) -- returns "1"
```

Comment: First of all, you should **indent** your code as well as the table. Their structure is not well readable as-is. (Also, why are you calling poor programmin language "LUA"? It may **explicitly** not be named in ALL CAPS, [as stated by e. g. Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_%28programming_language%29) [since that's considered shouting]. Its proper name is Lua.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your table structure, you don't need to do any looping; you can simply return the value from the table based on GUID and the category:

```
TestTable = {
  destGUID1 = {catagory1 = {A=1,B=5,C=3},catagory2 = {A=5,B=3,C=2}},
  destGUID2 = {catagory1 = {A=1,B=5,C=3},catagory2 = {A=5,B=3,C=2}}
}
function CatInfo(GUID,Cat)
  return TestTable[GUID][Cat].A
end
print(CatInfo('destGUID2','catagory1'))
```

This will print `1`. Note that `destGUID2` and `catagory1` need to be in quotes as those are strings.

Comment: @BenjaminCondrea, If that answers your question, you can accept the answer.

Comment: So using a table similar to this one, a function I made inputs data based on events. There will be many "destGUID", about 10 "catagory", and "A" is a timestamp, "B" is the calculated time before "C" resets back to 0, so "C" will be the number of times "catagory" returns true. Each inputted "destGUID" will be unique. So my question is, will this function be able to handle many "destGUID"?

Comment: Sure; as long as you have the structure as you described, it will be able to handle different GUID values (as it's not hardcoded in the function).